# Need some help using "if" in batch with variables and strings

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have used a For /f loop to read the values stored in a file, (the contents are at the bottom of my original post) and store parameters to variables that are generated on the fly using count+1, that way the number of parameters that can be used is open ended (as the intended use is to mount shares to drive letters there could be an arbitrary number of drives and thus parameters).

All of the parameters used must match and be known by the script, and each parameter has an associated setting. An example of this is the first parameter I defined in my file was ( Mode ) and its setting was ( LAN ). The way the For /f loops (two of them) were written along with the way the config file was written all of the used parameters would be assigned to a ( var# ) number using var!count! on the fly, and the associated setting would be assigned to ( avar# ).

However as the parameters can be listed in any order with the only requirement being that the associated setting be on the same line and after its delimiter symbol the number attached to var/avar serves only to make sure everything is stored in a unique variable.

I then attempt to use "if" to match the parameter stored in whatever var# the loop is working on, to known values useful to the project eg

```
var1 = Mode    avar1=LAN        as set by the For /f loop

if var!count!==Mode ( SET Mode=avar!count! )
```

Should hopefully match that var1 has the parameter Mode stored inside, so the Mode variable should be set to whatever is stored in avar1 ( Lan ) in this case (var1 goes with avar1, var2 goes with avar2, so on and so forth)

The problem is is that the if statements are never evaluating to true. A simplified code example follows, and I even for purposes of testing, manually set var1 near the top, even though that is supposed to be done by the For /F loop and it still didn't evaluate to true

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
SET count=1
FOR /f "eol=; skip=18 tokens=2 delims=#@" %%x  in (C:\OConf.ini) DO (
SET var!count!=%%x
SET /a count=!count!+1
echo value 1 is %%x  
)

SET count=1
FOR /f "eol=; skip=18 tokens=2 delims=@" %%x  in (C:\OConf.ini) DO (
SET avar!count!=%%x
SET /a count=!count!+1
echo value 2 is %%x  
) 


SET var1 == Mode 

:SetCounters
SET /a count=1 
:SetVars
echo test var!count! 

IF NOT DEFINED var!count! ( GOTO CleanOne )
if var!count! == Mode  ( Echo If this is seen then the "if" evaluated as true )
Echo The value of var1 equals  ( %var1% )
goto EOF

:CleanOne
Echo If you see this then var!count! is null

:EOF
Echo EOF2
```

For the person who mentioned the bit about EOF, I thought it worked as end of function without needing a tag, but at least one time I ran it, it didnt appear to work (though it may have been the IF statement failing ungracefully (has happened a few times))

===========================================================

## More complicated original post below, as per some advice, I simplified and clarified my question, which has been edited to above.

===========================================================

I am creating a windows 10 PE solution via winbuilder, ultimately I hope for it to be used from one of at least 3 methods (straight from a flash drive/dvd, multi-booted via a utility called easy2boot, and PXE booted from the network). However much of the functionality I have implemented requires some extra files to be accessible at drive letter Y:, but depending on how you booted that may mean mounting an image file, mounting a network share, or just reading the flash drive or dvd you booted from.

As such I am writing a script that runs before the shell loads at boot time. first thing it does is checks the root of every drive for a config file so if available it can go to town, if not available then it prompts the user to answer some questions and goes from there.

I have been writing what I will call 'simple scripts' for years, the kind that are static and linear in how they run, this is my first real attempt at what I am going to call a 'dynamic script' that has modular subroutines and loops and all paths will be relative and or user prompted but not hard coded in.

The main script that I have written for its part works nicely for itself and for the now mostly completed LAN subroutine, and echos the placeholder text nicely for the E2B and Flash subroutines.

I am currently working on the subroutine that checks for a config file and runs with that forgoing user input. I thought everything was going well getting in the scripting headspace forgetting to test for a while...

...When I do test, I find that the "IF" statements I am using are never evaluating to true, even if I manually set the variable and know it to be a match. I have tried every permutation I can think of with quotes, without, with percent and exclamation points, spaces, no space and differing placement possibilities... Googled and googled and one article I found here seemed like it should have worked but nothing I tried from it worked at all, but it inspired me to ask here!

The following is hard coded for simplicity of development to look for the config file at the root of my drive, the master script I plan to drop this into has a "if exist" loop that cycles through all drive letters to find it on any drive. Also I have commented on this script not only explaining what does what, but also where exactly I am having trouble. I also commented out a few duplicated things that are the results of my experimentation in getting this to work. The script as it is now will read the intended values and assign them to incremented variables and echo them back to show its worked, but then fails when it tries to determine the content having been read and assign them to the proper variables to be used in making stuff happen

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
::sets the primary counter for the "For" Loop
SET count=1
:: FOR loop to set varibles for the descriptive name of the setting to be 
adjusted for use in
:: determining what the setting value is to adjust
FOR /f "eol=; skip=18 tokens=2 delims=#@" %%x  in (C:\OConf.ini) DO (
SET var!count!=%%x
SET /a count=!count!+1
echo value 1 is %%x  
)
::sets the primary counter for the "For" Loop
SET count=1
::FOR loop to determine the setting values that go with each descriptive Name
FOR /f "eol=; skip=18 tokens=2 delims=@" %%x  in (C:\OConf.ini) DO (
SET avar!count!=%%x
SET /a count=!count!+1
echo value 2 is %%x  
) 

:MyLabel 

::diagnostic code to reference what value is being stored
echo  this is var1: %var1%
echo  this is avar1: %avar1%
echo  this is var2: %var2%
echo  this is avar2: %avar2%
echo  this is var3: %var3%
echo  this is avar3: %avar3%
echo  this is var4: %var4%
echo  this is avar4: %avar4%
echo  this is var5: %var5%
echo  this is avar5: %avar5%
echo  this is var6: %var6%
echo  this is avar6: %avar6%
echo  this is var7: %var7%
echo  this is avar7: %avar7%
echo  this is var8: %var8%
echo  this is avar8: %avar8%
echo  this is var9: %var9%
echo  this is avar9: %avar9%
echo  this is var10: %var10%
echo  this is avar10: %avar10%
echo  this is var11: %var11%
echo  this is avar11: %avar11%
echo  this is var12: %var12%
echo  this is avar12: %avar12%

::echo  this is avar1: %avar1%
::echo  this is avar2: %avar2%
::echo  this is avar3: %avar3%
::echo  this is avar4: %avar4%
::echo  this is avar5: %avar5%
::echo  this is avar6: %avar6%
::echo  this is avar7: %avar7%
::echo  this is avar8: %avar8%
::echo  this is avar9: %avar9%
::echo  this is avar10: %avar10%
::echo  this is avar11: %avar11%
::echo  this is avar12: %avar12%

::in my sample script I am testing against var/avar is known to be null this is test code
echo  this is avar13: %avar13% test
::this code is to show me what part of the script has or has not executed
echo this is not final



:SetCounters
::Set primary counter for script advancement
SET /a count=1 
::Set drive letter counter so it can be compared to the share counter
SET /a D=1    
::Set network share counter so it can be compared to the drive letter counter
SET /a S=1    
:SetVars
::Subrotine to fill in variables for use in the up coming action subrutines
::Diagnostic line added when things were not working right
echo test var!count! D is %D% S is %S%

::escape subrutine so when all values have been filled in, this loop ends and goes to use
IF NOT DEFINED var!count! ( GOTO CleanOne )

:: This is the heavy lifting of this subrutine (also currently non functional for unknown reasons)
:: If bank compares the value of var# (where # is a counter set number) to known valid values, when
:: the valid value is found to match, its associated setting held in avar# is to the batch varible
:: of the same name. Commented out code is either non functional or untest but a new approach concocted
:: before testing, but the need to return to it may come up  so not removed. denoted as not part of
:: this description by adding a preceeding astrik 
:: ========================================================================================

:: Mode is the first test & despite everything I have tried will not evaluate to true
:: tried multiple iterations of including quotes (or not), exclamations and percents symbols
:: around the varibles different ways "var!count!" var!count! %var%!count! 
%var!count!% !var!!count! !var!count!!
:: and a bunch of others, similar iterations around mode, tried spaces and no spaces next to the equal symbols
:: also tried reversing the order of the comparison... *******HELP*******
::*if "%var%!count!" == "Mode" ( Set Mode=avar2 echo test mode %Mode% )
:: Next line is bastardized to simply see when the expression evaluates to true
:: if Mode == !var!!count!  ( Echo Equal )
:: next commented out command is supposed to remove quotes if present to prevent issues, will return to this
:: concept once the issue with the IF statements is dealt with
::*SET Mode=%avar!count!:"=% 
:: also a diagnostic command 
::*echo test mode %Mode%



::=======================================================
:: lines between here and the next divider for me have been temporarily cut to another file  to reduce clutter
:: and save my sanity while I takle the problem. pasted back to demonstraight intended functionality.

:: Mode has 3 valid options currently, Flash/DVD, LAN, E2B and will be used to either mount a image file on a E2B
:: drive to a drive letter, or to mount (possibly multiple) network shares to drive letters
if var!count!==Mode ( SET Mode=avar!count! )
::if var!count!==Mode ( SET Mode=%avar!count!:"=% )

:: Perf is short for performance and is to determine if the install driver packs subroutine should run to increase performance
:: and or recognize otherwise unknown devices, declining this uses only baked in drivers. Valid options are Yes/No
if var!count!==Perf ( Set Perf=avar!count!)
::if var!count!==Perf ( SET Perf=%avar!count!:"=% )

:: ImgPth is for the image path to be mounted to the Y:, currently it is only intended that 1 image be mounted however
:: as I write this I realize the way I am approaching mounting network shares could allow multiple images to be added also
if var!count!==ImgPth ( Set ImgPth=avar!count!)
::if var!count!==ImgPth ( SET ImgPth=%avar!count!:"=% )

:: NumDrv is supposed to be how many network shares were to be mounted so the script could allocate enough varibles
:: I have sense adopted a new approach that can auto-detect and just run, haven't removed yet
if var!count!==NumDrv ( Set NumDrv=avar!count!)
::if var!count!==NumDrv ( SET NumDrv=%avar!count!:"=% )

:: Server is used to name the server that has the network share on it that will get mounted to a drive letter
:: the tools used only support one server connection via one user name, so this can only be set once.
:: eg \\server01\something\share would translate to server01  (no need for slashes)
if var!count!==Server ( Set Server=avar!count!)
::if var!count!==Server ( SET Server=%avar!count!:"=% )

:: Usr is the user name to authenticate with the server to access the network share
:: the tools used only support one server connection via one user name, so this can only be set once.
if var!count!==Usr ( Set Usr=avar!count!)
::if var!count!==Usr ( SET Usr=%avar!count!:"=% )

::Pass is the password to use in authenticating with the server
:: the tools used only support one server connection via one user name, so this can only be set once.
if var!count!==Pass ( Set Pass=avar!count!)
::if var!count!==Pass ( SET Pass=%avar!count!:"=% )

::DrvLtr denotes what drive letter you want the network share mounted to. X: will already be in use by the system
:: if using on a computer with windows installed on local HDD then C: will be in use. If newer windows with recovery
:: partitions and or otherwise multiple drives/partitions D: E: will also likely be in use. Y: is a special case and 
:: ultimatly the point of this entire script. Core files to boot and opperate are loaded to the X: ram disk, however 
:: to save RAM and increase compatibility additional functionality that requires additional files not stored in the 
:: ramdisk need to be mounted to Y: and Y: is reserved for this use only. So do not use C: D: E: X: (Y: unless its for 
:: the specified files)
if var!count!==DrvLtr ( 
Set DrvLtr!DL!=avar!count!
::Set DrvLtr!DL!=%avar!count!:"=%
::Next bit was intended to be a diagnostic message, alas the test never got that far
Echo DrvLtr Subroutine has run for the !DL! time and stored %DrvLtr%!DL! for use 
:: the counter being modified below allows for it to be determined how many times this subroutine has run
:: by the time this loop exits it should match the number of times the Share routine has run, if it doesn't
:: then there is an error, but by taking the smaller number and running the mount share command only the 
:: lessar times it can be assured each share has a drive letter and vice versa
SET /a DL=!DL!+1
)
:: path to the network Share, multiple of these can be mounted to different drive letters
:: eg \\server01\something\share would translate to something\share, or if the share isnt in a sub folder
:: eg \\server01\share then it would translate to just    share   (slashes only used if more then one folder deep)
if var!count!==Share ( 
Set Share!SH!=avar!count!
::Set DrvLtr!SH!=%avar!count!:"=%
Echo DrvLtr Subrutine has run for the !SH! time and stored %DrvLtr%!SH! for use
:: the counter being modified below allows for it to be determined how many times this subroutine has run
:: by the time this loop exits it should match the number of times the Share routine has run, if it doesn't
:: then there is an error, but by taking the smaller number and running the mount share command only the 
:: lessar times it can be assured each share has a drive letter and vice versa
SET /a SH=!SH!+1
)
:: advances the main counter so the next pass through the loop doesn't use the same variable and thus the same information 
SET /a count=!count!+1 
:: its commented out for troubleshooting but this goto is to repeat the loop
::goto :SetVars
pause
:: the above if statements currently are nonfunctional, the below is my first draft at takling the idea of mounting multiple network shares
:: before realizing the approach had some limitations in how drive letters and their respective shares could be listed in the config file
:: originally intended that the config file would list either the letter then the share, next letter next share, or possibly share then letter
:: this code was then tweaked so the config file could accept letter, share, share, letter, letter, share; however having more then two letters 
:: and or shares in sequence would conceptially (I never tested this code) break the code, and a bathroom break brainstorm would clue me into 
:: much simpler code that shouldnt care how the drive letters and shares are listed as long as there are equal numbers of them, and if theres not
:: a still useable fail can be acheved by using the lower number of how many shares listed vs drive letters 

REM attempting  subroutine rewrite to be completly agnostic to drive verses share ordering, commented out subroutine in case
REM I fail and or I need to use parts of this
REM #(if sh) commented out as more versitile and similar functionality provided by adding another counter advance near the end
REM #this should allow the drive letters or shares to be listed back to back and still be set as long as its still grouped to 
REM #one side or the other with its other value (S= share D= Drive: DSDSDS was the original plan, DSSDDS or SDDSSD would be prevented
REM #by this method but would work with the counter advance)
::if var!count!==DrvLtr (                                                     
REM Checking for drive letter option
::if SH==0 (            REM checking if share has already been set this plus next option prevents a required order of things, though the options must be set together
::Set DrvLtr=avar!count!                       REM Sets the Drive Letter value 
::SET /a count=!count!+1                     REM If share hasnt been set, advances the counter so the share can be set
::if var!count!==Share ( Set Share=avar!count!        REM sets the share
::Set /p DL=1              REM notates that the share has been set so the next subroutine wont muck things up trying to do the same thing
::echo DrvLtr Subrutine has run varibles are %DrvLtr% and %Share%    REM Diagnostic message to know if this subrutine ran and if so did it set correctly
::SET /a count=!count!+1        REM advances the counter so presumably the share subrutine wont run as it was set here
::)
::else ( Echo Share set errored )
::)
:CleanOne

:: makes sure the number of drive letters requested matches the number of shares being mounted or if not uses the lesser number
Set /a Dnum=!DL!
set /a Snum=!SH!
If %Dnum% LEQ %Snum% set /a RC=%Dnum%
If %Snum% LEQ %Dnum% set /a RC=%Snum%
goto :CleanTwo

:CleanTwo
REM to modify later, currently echoing to test current script operation
:: this is when I decided to test and discovered the broken IF statements
:: this subroutine was conceptualized and removing all quotes that maybe stored in variables, however before writing something to do that
:: I found sample code that could do that on the fly and wrote it into the if statements, sense being commented out as I tackle why the IF's are broken
Echo Mode equals %Mode%
Echo Perf equals %Perf%
Echo NumDrv equals %NumDrv%
Echo Server equals %Server%
Echo Usr equals %Usr%
Echo Pass equals %Pass%
Echo DrvLtr equals %DrvLtr%
Echo Share equals %Share%
Echo DrvLtr2 equals %DrvLtr2%
Echo Share2 equals %Share2%
Echo DrvLtr3 equals %DrvLtr3%
Echo Share3 equals %Share3%

:: after making sure nothing is muddled with quotes, and maybe slashes, and likely inserting some code above the SetVars rutine to set all to either upper/lower 
:: case to prevent issue, the assigned variables will be used. 

:: Flash/dvd will simply ask for the performance option and look for a DriverPacks and install them 
:: if performance mode is desired. 

:: E2B, is for use with Easy2Boot using a .imgptn file which gets mapped to the MBR of the flash drive (it's a compatibility hack for uefi)
:: easy2boot supports other image files but the functionality of automatically unmounting, and remapping to a drive letter are automatically done with baked in options, 
:: plus access to the E2B drive proper is never lost, with .imgptn being mapped to the drive via the MBR all access to the main drive is lost until you run a script 
:: provided the developer to restore the MBR to its original state. E2B mode in this script is intended to call that script (well a bastardized version that doesnt need
:: user input, via loops and auto detection (upcoming, my previous version I tweaked for my PE3 build years ago, was hard coded for set options that were true about 90% time,
:: everything about this project as opposed to my old project is to be modular, relative, and dynamic so hard coding things esp things that dont work all the time are an antithesis)
:: Once the script is run to restore the original MBR and primary drive access is restored, the image "path\file" stored in ImgPth will be mounted to the Y: using imdisk.

:: Lan is intended for PXE boot situations and will mount a network share that contains the files needed for Y:  to that drive letter, and additionally any extra shares indicated

:: performance mode will then run or not as specified, followed by starting the shell




:MyLabel 
:: Original placment of this diagnostic readout, some iterations of the broken IF statements prevented the script from completing 
:: and this was never seen, and in takling this problem I needed to see if these were set so copied above

echo  this is var1: %var1%
echo  this is avar1: %avar1%
echo  this is var2: %var2%
echo  this is avar2: %avar2%
echo  this is var3: %var3%
echo  this is avar3: %avar3%
echo  this is var4: %var4%
echo  this is avar4: %avar4%
echo  this is var5: %var5%
echo  this is avar5: %avar5%
echo  this is var6: %var6%
echo  this is avar6: %avar6%
echo  this is var7: %var7%
echo  this is avar7: %avar7%
echo  this is var8: %var8%
echo  this is avar8: %avar8%
echo  this is var9: %var9%
echo  this is avar9: %avar9%
echo  this is var10: %var10%
echo  this is avar10: %avar10%
echo  this is var11: %var11%
echo  this is avar11: %avar11%
echo  this is var12: %var12%
echo  this is avar12: %avar12%

::echo  this is avar1: %avar1%
::echo  this is avar2: %avar2%
::echo  this is avar3: %avar3%
::echo  this is avar4: %avar4%
::echo  this is avar5: %avar5%
::echo  this is avar6: %avar6%
::echo  this is avar7: %avar7%
::echo  this is avar8: %avar8%
::echo  this is avar9: %avar9%
::echo  this is avar10: %avar10%
::echo  this is avar11: %avar11%
::echo  this is avar12: %avar12%

echo  this is avar13: %avar13% test
echo this is not final
goto test2

:Final
Echo this is final

:EOF

echo done 




pause
:: a command I refrenced, from something I used a while back

::SET count=1
::FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`Net User %Username%`) DO (
::  SET var!count!=%%F
::  SET /a count=!count!+1
::  SET Shell=Chrome
)





::========================================================
:: Also these are diagnostic commands and subroutines that may share names with some of the above that was
:: temporarily cut out as I takle the problem.
:: Echo %var1% is still var1 right
:: goto EOF

:: :CleanOne
:: Echo CleanOne 13

:: :EOF
:: Echo EOF2


:: commented these out
```

Also for reference, the sample config file I have been testing against follows:

```
//Mode Declares how the system should mount additional required files, based on how the system was booted
//
//Performance mode Loads drivers either from the Y: or from the E2B flash drive, depending on Mode.
//Performance mode may take plus or minus 5 minutes to fully load, and installs all relevant drivers found in the 
//DriverPacks folder in Y: (on Flash/LAN) or on the E2B drive (E2B), For your wait time you get proper performance
//From all your devices, and or visibility if not otherwise recognized, as long as the drivers are in the folder.
//
//Network drive specifies the Server, Share, Login Credentials and the desired Drive letter to mount the share too.
//Y: is reserved for Files required by the Diagnostic Enviornment, LAN requires the first loaded share to contain 
//Non-Wim files found in the .iso. Flash/E2B can also mount Network shares but Y: must not be used.
//
//No Slashes are required when entering the network parameters, unless your username requires a domain prefix
//you may only connect to one server, and only use one user to login, however shares are only limited by available 
//Drive letters. X: Y: are reserved by the environment, if the computer used has a HDD with windows on it C: will be 
//used, if modern windows then there will be additional partitions loaded if they are not hidden. 
//Advise not to use B:C:D:E:X:Y:

//==========================================================================
;//(Mode can be: Flash/E2B/LAN)
!#Mode @ LAN
;//(Performance Mode can be: Yes/No)
!#Perf @ No   
;//(Network Drive Parameters)  
;//(Number of network Shares to mount including Y: if LAN booting)
!#NumDrv @ 3    
;//(Server to connect to on LAN)
!#Server @ oc3-omega01    
;//(User name to authenticate with the server)
!#Usr @ SomeName    
;//(Password to authenticate with the Server)
!#Pass @ SomePassword    
;//(Drive letter to assign the first share)
!#DrvLtr @ Y     
;//(Share on server to map to drive)
!#Share @ OmegaDR     
;//(Repeat DrvLtr and Share lines for as many shares as you are mapping, Do not reuse drive letters)
!#DrvLtr @ Z     
!#Share @ Data     
!#DrvLtr @ U     
!#Share @ "Manual Backups"
```

I should say there is nothing really confidential about this so it can be shared, as when I am done, yes it will suit my goal of having //one// image that can be dynamically configured for multiple uses, but I also plan to share it so others with winpe projects can benefit.

This project is actually an update of sorts, as I have a fully functioning PE3(win7 based) set of tools, but I discovered the hard way it would not see GUID drives on a UEFI system. Also the scripts used in my PE3 images were static and while they worked most of the time, every once and awhile they wouldn't because whatever exact thing I typed in the scripts didn't match whatever random new machine. this time I am trying to make a universal startup script.

Comment: There's an awful lot to process there for what looks like it should be a much simpler question. Perhaps you could try to find a way to demonstrate your issue in a more minimal script? i.e.  a [mcve].

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do: **If var!count!==Mode**. Pretty sure this is where you are confused.

Comment: This is not what I call a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

```
if var!count!==Share (
```

will be resolved to

```
if var1==Share (
```

assuming `count` has the value `1`.

`IF` is quite literal - the two strings either side of the comparison operator are compared literally, so the instruction is "if *the literal string* var1 is equal to *the literal string* Share "

You need the *contents of* `var1`, which is `!var%count%!` That is - two stages - first replace any `%count%` with the content of `count` and then retrieve the content of the result.

This is why `!var!` should not be used for the general `value of a variable` case, but reserved for where this two-stage resolution is required and for when the required variable is being changed within a loop.

BTW - `if` has a `/i` switch to make the comparison case-insensitive.

`set var` will list *all* variables starting `var`

`:EOF` is predefined as literally "end of file". `goto :eof` is predefined as "go to end-of-file" (ie exit the current routine) and you are likely to encounter problems if you define your own label `:eof` - for instance, `goto eof` will quite happily reach your label, but `goto :eof` will exit the routine (another reason I don't use the `goto :label` syntax)

Comment: Thank you Magoo, there is some genuine good information in there I needed, not the least of which is that "if /i" switch. 

The `if var!count!==Share (` tid bit though was not only known but being exploited.for that use. a For /f loop is setting those variables from a file and that part works. The part that does not work is using IF to match the generated on the fly var!count! to a declared variable and to set its value if the condition is true. the problem is the "if" statements no matter how I finagle them won't evaluate to true. Taking some advice I will be posting simpler example soon.